# Linear voltage regulator input voltage drop error. What's the problem?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am doing a homework project, making an AC to DC converter using a rectifier circuit and regulator.

The homework conditions are:

We must use an AC input voltage with Vpp = 20V and frequency = 1kHz.
We must get an output DC constant positive +9V or above.

My thought (diagram) is

Input AC signal -> voltage doubler -> peak rectifier -> regulator

That is:

[image]

I measured the above voltage.  This is the result:

[image]

Good result. Right? So I connected an LM7812CT to node C2. Like this:

[image]

The problem is here. The measured voltage graph looks like this:

[image]

What? The input voltage to the voltage regulator drops a lot. I can't get the result what I want. I found that Rsig (power supplier resistance) has much voltage so the input voltage to voltage regulator is very low.

Why does this happen? I think that the input voltage regulator is very small so voltage dividing makes this situation, but it's not clear.

I want to know the reason for the voltage drop.

Comment: why do you do a voltage doubler if your V_in_pp is already higher than your V_out = 9V?

Comment: Because i guess that i must make an input voltage to Voltage regulator higher than 12V.

Comment: Have you considered using a "bridge rectifier" circuit? Maybe your AC input voltage is "floating" (like a winding from a transformer would be) so there's no need to connect one side of the AC source to ground. Why is there a 1 k ohm series resistor, it limits the current and wastes power.

Comment: Yes, i try many cases : using transformer.. using bridge rectifier..
But! it appears similar result. Rsig has many voltage!! 
The reason why i consider Rsig is...

Comment: 12 V is *your* requirement. The actual problem statement said 9V, which is even less than half the V_in_pp, which makes everything easier. You're imagining problems that aren't there: build a boring bridge rectifier, capacitor, 9V voltage regulator, done.

Comment: At first, i didn't consider Rsig ( There is no Rsig ). So Pspice gives me a result what i want. I'm happy and i try making "real circuit" based on Pspice. 
But real circuit gives me a result in this post. At first, i can't know what makes this. After trying many tests, i understand this comes from Rsig(Maybe in the power supply). I try test and i found that Rsig = 1kohm.
After knowing this, i add Rsig to the pspice circuit. And real circuit and pspice circuit give me same result. So i'm sure that Rsig is the problem.

Comment: To Marcus Muller

i know. 9V is less than 12V. And we don't need to make voltage doubler.

But TA gives me a component Linear voltage regulator LM7812CT. So i think it's good to use this one. But, Now, i;m going to forgive up making this circuit. I'm too tired..

Comment: well, as Bimpelrekkie says, you've got an illogical 1kΩ resistor in there, I don't know why, but that obviously limits the current you can draw; then, you seem to have questionable simulation parameters.

Comment: I comment the reason why i add Rsig to the pspice circuit above.

Comment: Does the output have to be regulated or just "9V and above"? The other suggestion is to have a look these standard rectifier topologies: http://hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf

Comment: To ErikR

Well, i hope to use a component regulator... If i don't use it, the problem is nothing.
I just want to use a regulator because professor gives me.. He says that as possible as you can, you should reduce ripple voltage.

Comment: @Wutdreheram I read that comment, but it just says "I think there is supposed to be a Rsig, I don't know where it comes from".

Comment: @ Marcus

Yes, Rsig comes from My thinking(Just my guess)

But, when i add this to the pspice circuit, pspice and real circuit make same result. So I convince my guess...

Comment: REMOVE Rsig and series cap. Use full wave rectifier. Use 9V regulator. Finish assinment with good results :-).

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested in the comments, this will work much better:

*build a boring bridge rectifier, capacitor, 9V voltage regulator, done*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvrs23.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a "classic" linear power supply circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EE stack exchange!
The circuit should work, but the numbers are against you.

There's no perfect voltage regulator; the LM7812, for instance, draws approximately 8 mA of current for its  internal amplifiers and voltage
reference, so the 1 k ohm resistor will lose about 8V.   The
fact that your rectifier is a doubler, makes that 16V, and the capacitors
are not zero impedance (22 uF at 1 kHz is about 7 ohms), so you can
expect about another 20 ohms in two capacitors and two diodes.
Lower that resistance, use bigger capacitors, and... it should work.

Of course, there's also usually going to be a load on the output, using that regulated power that your circuit provides.   You want to simulate
that, too.